# shell regex not found (number, length and K letter)

Tags: regex, bash, shell

my code or regex not found, im tried with:

```
'^([0-9]{7,8})+([K|0-9]{1})'

'#[0-9]{7,8}[K 0-9]{1}'

'#[0-9]{7,8}[K 0-9]{1}'

"^([0-9]{7,8})+([K|0-9]{1})$"
```

*i need return (1234567 or 12345678) + K or number (not found \d)

ex: 123456789  12345678K  12345678

*with this regex '^[0-9]{7,8}[K|0-9]{1}' return:

ok 184587939

ok 17678977K

ok 186613074

ok 18661307Z ***(dont work the last digit)***

invalido 18R613074

ok 1845879398888888 ***(not length found)***

ok 18458793U

invalido 18661G074

invalido 18661G07T

ok 18458793

invalido 1845E793

```
#!/bin/bash
var='^([0-9]{7,8})+([K|0-9]{1})$'
for LINEA in `cat rut.txt ` #LINEA guarda el resultado del fichero rut.txt
do
    rut=`echo $LINEA | cut -d ":" -f1` #Extrae rut
    rut=$(echo $rut | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')
    while :
    do
        if [[ $rut =~ $var ]];then ()
             #$rut >> rutok.txt
             echo $rut | cat >> rutok.txt
            echo $rut' ok'
            break
        else
             #$rut >> rutinv.txt
             echo $rut | cat >> rutinv.txt
            echo $rut' inv'
            break

        fi
    done
done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If Iunderstand you correctly, I believe this is what you're after.

`^([0-9]{8}|[0-9]{7}K)$`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 ^([0-9]{7,8})([k0-9])$
```

For

> 184587939
>          17678977K
>          186613074

and `^([0-9]{7,8})([a-z0-9])$` For

> 184587939
>          17678977K
>          186613074
>          17678977A
>          18661307B
>          17678977U
>          18661307L

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely unclear, but in addition, your code is incredibly overcomplicated.  You seem to be looking for simply `grep` and `grep -v`.  Looping over the lines in a file with `for` is definitely wrong (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) but a `while read -r` loop is also usually an antipattern.  In the general case, these are usually examples of an Awk script begging to be born.

```
cut -d : -f1 rut.txt |
tr A-Z a-z |
awk '/^([0-9]{7,8})([KZ0-9])$/ { print >>"rutok.txt"; next }
    { print >> "rutinv.txt" }'
```

The `{1}` repetition is just superfluous (otherwise we'd have to write `h{1}t{1}t{1}p{1}` etc to match a simple string!) and inside a character class, you just enumerate the character ranges; if you don't want to match a literal `|` character, don't put it in the character class.

`([0-9]{7,8})+` means one or more repetitions of 7 or 8 numbers; so 7, 8, 14, 15, 16, 21, ... repetitions.  According to the exposition, this is not what you want.

I'm *guessing* the regex above covers your case: seven or eight digits and a K or one more digit.

Moreover, returning to your shell script, you should not use uppercase for your own variables (these are reserved for system use); and you need to quote your strings unless you specifically want the shell to perform token splitting and wildcard expansion on the values (though that's probably likely to be harmless here).  Finally, the `while` loop does not seem to serve any useful purpose, as you `break` out of it on the first iteration in every case.

Comment: For a production script, I would refactor the `cut` and `tr` into the Awk script as well.